# Sklearn inverse_transform error doesn't match the broadcast shape

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I load keras model to test data with this code.

```
sc = StandardScaler()
X = sc.fit_transform(df.astype(float))

print(X)

model = load_model('my_model.h5')

p =model.predict(X)
print(p)
real_pred = sc.inverse_transform(p)
print(real_pred)
```

when I run this code it show error.

```
ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (2100,1) doesn't match the broadcast shape (2100,5)
```

I try to edit code like this.

```
sc.inverse_transform(p)[:,0]
sc.inverse_transform(p)[:,[0]]
```

But it still not work. How to fix it?

Comment: Probably your dataframe df has 5 columns, and your model prediction ends up with one column

Comment: Model get input 5 columns, output ends up with one column.

Comment: @user58519 it seems to me that your model is a recurrent model which take 5 input to make a single prediction, like LSTM or GRU.

Comment: Otherwise, it can be a categorical model where 2100 is the number of samples you have, 5 is the dimension of feature, and it goes through a model to make a prediction of which class the input comes from. in this case, you can't do inverse transform,

Comment: Your `X` has shape is (2100,1)?

Comment: X shape is (2100, 5). p shape is (2100, 1). p is output of the model.